# Ownership of models with Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-models

I'm using Devise for the first time with my Rails 4 project and I am trying to figure out how to lock down ownership of models to certain users.

For example, if a user creates a model only that user should be able to do the following to it,

- list all models belonging to the user
- view
- edit
- update
- delete

So basically all crud actions should be restricted to the user who owns the model.

**How would you you go about implementing ownership in a DRY idiomatic manner?** It seems like I could do a check in the controller to see if the user owns the current object, but then if the object is used by another controller or used as part of a nested update I have to reimplement the logic, but it doesn't seem right for the model to have access to the current user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would check out the gem [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan), it assigns permissions to users, so if a user has a role of an owner is has the permissions for all the CRUD actions

RailsApp has an example, albeit in rails 3.2, https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-bootstrap-devise-cancan, that uses devise and cancan

Hope this helps

Comment: That looks really good, I don't know I missed that since I've been browsing Railscasts extensively while trying to pick up Rails. I will check it out.

Comment: No worries man! I'm attaching the railscast [192-Authorization-With-CanCan](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan) just in case

Answer (score 0):

i wrote this link https://github.com/x1wins/tutorial-rails-rest-api#authorize

```
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
      def is_owner user_id
        unless user_id == @current_user.id
          render json: nil, status: :forbidden
          return
        end
      end
    
      def is_owner_object data
        if data.nil? or data.user_id.nil?
          return render status: :not_found
        else
          is_owner data.user_id
        end
      end
    end
    
    # How to Use
    class PostsController < ApplicationController
        before_action only: [:update, :destroy, :destroy_attached] do
          is_owner_object @post ##your object
        end
    end
```